# Reverting Unstaged Changes to Single File in Git

Tags: git

I have about 20 files which have unstaged changes since the last commit. I would like to discard changes in one of these files while keeping the changes to the rest intact. How could I do that?

Comment: Usefull question, after all, at least for _git_ begginer. Straight to the point, very precise, as well as the accepted answer.

Comment: I didn't understand all the down-votes either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git checkout -- <file-path>`